# Nodejs Mongoose select a entire document but only with selected items in a property array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I'm new to nodejs and currently i'm developing a Web API using nodejs, express and mongoose. Can anyone help me on following mongoose query.

```
var EventSchema = new Schema({

      event_title: {
            type: String,
            required: true
      },

      service_order: [{
                  _id:{
                    type: String
                  },
                  service : {
                        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                        ref: "Service"
                  }

      }]    
});
```

I want to select a entire Event document but only with selected service_order items in that array

ex :-
this is a entire Event document

```
{
   _id: "sample_id",
   name: 'some name',
   "service_order": [
                        {
                         "_id": "1"
                         "service": {
                                    "_id": "59c005524d9c141fe0d95f15"
                        },
                        {
                         "_id": "2"
                         "service": {
                                    "_id": "59c005524d9c141fe0d95f18"
                        },
                        {
                         "_id": "3"
                         "service": {
                                    "_id": "59c005524d9c141fe0d95f18"
                        },
                        {
                         "_id": "4"
                         "service": {
                                    "_id": "59c005524d9c141fe0d95f18"
                        }
                    ],
}
```

But I want to execute a single mongoose query which can give this as the output

```
{
       _id: "sample_id",
       name: 'some name',
       "service_order": [
                            {
                             "_id": "1"
                             "service": {
                                        "_id": "59c005524d9c141fe0d95f15"
                            },
                            {
                             "_id": "2"
                             "service": {
                                        "_id": "59c005524d9c141fe0d95f18"
                            }
                        ],
    }
```

Initially I know the Event id ("sample_id") and the ids of service_orders that i want to select ( ["1","2"] ).

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongodb aggregate to achieve that

don't forget to replace `sample_id` and `["1" , "2"]` with your dynamic data

Check the code below:

```
db.event.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { _id: "sample_id" } 
    },
    {
        $unwind: { path: "$service_order" }
    },
    {
        $match : { 'service_order._id' : { $in : [ "1" , "2"]} } 
    },
    {
        $group : { 
            _id: { _id: "$_id", "name": "$name"},
            service_order: { $addToSet: "$service_order" },
        }
    },
    {
        $project : {
            _id : "$_id._id",
            name : "$_id.name",
            service_order : 1
        }
    }
])
```